# Перевод UnicodeString to float

Tags: c++

Как перевести из `UnicodeString` в `float`?

В моём случае:

```
 float eps;  
 eps=Edit1->Text;
```

Comment: Наверное `swscanf()` надо использовать.

Comment: не,не получается. Выдаёт [BCC32 Error] Unit1.cpp(22): E2034 Cannot convert 'UnicodeString' to 'const wchar_t *'
  Full parser context
    Unit1.cpp(20): parsing: void _fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *)

Answer (score 2):

Использовать [`wstringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/wstringstream/)

```
#include <sstream>

...

const wchar_t * number = L"3.14";

wstringstream s;
s << number;

float f;
s >> f;
```

http://ideone.com/P3PoMW

Если есть возможность использовать boost, то можно попробовать `lexical_cast`

```
const float f = boost::lexical_cast<const float>(L"3.14");l
```